# Error on build libcurl with mingw on windows 11

Tags: c, cmake, mingw, libcurl

I see an error while build libCurl using CMake and MingW on windows.
I have MingW, windows kit and MSYS2 install on my PC.

Before Building LibCurl, my CMake file build Openssl and Zlib and everything is fine.
I face this error and I don't know what i missed.

```
curl\lib\easy_lock.h:32:31: error: 'SRWLOCK_INIT' undeclared here (not in a function)
   32 | #define CURL_SIMPLE_LOCK_INIT SRWLOCK_INIT
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
\curl\lib\easy.c:97:34: note: in expansion of macro 'CURL_SIMPLE_LOCK_INIT'
   97 | static curl_simple_lock s_lock = CURL_SIMPLE_LOCK_INIT;
```

I built my CMake file on ubuntu 20.04 and everything is fine.

What i missed?

PS: I Use libcurl latest release for build. Version 7.84.0

PS2: This my CMake Build Command

```
ExternalProject_Add(curl
    DEPENDS openssl
    URL "https://github.com/curl/curl/releases/download/curl-7_84_0/curl-7.84.0.tar.gz"
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
        -DCURL_USE_OPENSSL=ON
        -DCURL_STATICLIB=1
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0
        -DCURL_USE_LIBPSL=OFF
        -DUSE_LIBIDN2=OFF
        -DCURL_USE_LIBSSH2=OFF
        -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=${OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR}
        -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        -DOPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS=TRUE
        -DBUILD_CURL_EXE=0
)
```

Comment: What version of mingw?

Comment: I Don't know the version of my MingW. I download and install it from sourceforge today. I think I am on latest version. how can I find the version? My GCC version is 9.2.0 @RetiredNinja

Comment: MinGW project is moving from Sourceforge and does not look to be fresh there. Try the latest version of MSYS2 from https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: I have to say thanks to you @273K using mingw under msys solved my problem. best regards.

Comment: We have fixed some easy_lock-related problems (in master) that shipped in 7.84.0.